# Samba share on ubuntu with Linux VM

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, samba

I have an Ubuntu local machine and an Ubuntu VM.

I have tried to share my web root folder with my local machine, using Virtualbox share folder, but can't get it up.

Now I want to install samba and use it as a network drive rather than a share, I have a bridge connection already, but not sure how to.

So on which Ubuntu do I install Samba, local or VM, and how do I add it on the other one?

Comment: Samba is a server, and smbclient is client to that server. So you should install Samba on that machine where share is located. BTW, you should (and it would be preferrable) install Guest Additions to your VM in order to use VBox share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Preferrable way

If you want to use folder from your *host machine* inside your *guest machine*, it would be preferrable to use VirtualBox Guest Additions. For installing them you should:

1. Find Menu -> Devices -> Install Guest Additions.
2. Run `sudo /cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` inside your guest system.

Then run `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$GID share ~/host` inside guest. `Share` is the name of the share.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders).

## Suggested way

But, if you still want to use Samba, then you should do this:

1. Install `samba` and `system-config-samba` on host machine and configure your share. Be sure that you enable access to that share to some local user.

   Example share (inside `/etc/samba/smb.conf`):

   ```
   [exch]
       comment = Exchange
       path = /home/karimov-danil/Public/exch
       writeable = yes
   ;   browseable = yes
       valid users = karimov-danil, nobody
   ```
2. Install `cifs-utils` onto your guest machine. Then type:

   ```
   sudo mount.cifs -o user=USER,pass=PASSWORD //server/share ~/share
   ```

   `USER` and `PASSWORD` are username and password for that user to whom you did enable access to the `share`. And `server` is the name of the *host machine*.

Comment: look at log here http://pastebin.com/VnqUZXq0, `Be sure that you enable access to that share to some local user.` How do I do that?

Comment: I don't have `VBoxGuestAdditions.sh` inside my guest system. Thank you very much for all your help

Comment: Oops, `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, I meant. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, I actually got around this all by using Eclipses remote repository feature through SSH...